# android + retrieve data from the mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, error-handling

i am creating a mobile application that have access to an external database to retrieve some data but the problem is in the log cat  i got error can anyone help me i will appreciate that

as shown in the log cat the system the error is in  **HttpResponse response  = httpclient.execute(httppost);**so how to fix this ??

## TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java

```
package com.taseen.apps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.array;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestExternalDatabaseActivity extends Activity {

    TextView resultView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testexternaldatabase);

    resultView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    getData();



    }


   public void getData() 
   {
       String  result = "";
       InputStream isr = null;

       try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("127.0.0.2/getAllCustomers.php");
           HttpResponse response  = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           try {
            isr = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("log-tag", "Error in  connection"+e.toString());
        resultView.setText("could not connect to database");


        //convert response to string 

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Log-tag", "Error converting  result" +e.toString());




    //parse json data

            try {
                String s ="";
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i = 0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    s =  s +
                            "Name: "+json.getString("FirstName")+" "+json.getString("LastName")+"\n"+
                            "Age: "+json.getString("Age")+"\n"+
                            "Mobile Used: "+json.getString("Mobile")+"\n\n";

                }

                resultView.setText(s);
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("log-tag", "Error parsing data"+e.toString());
            }


    } catch (IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }





   } catch (IOException e5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e5.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

## log cat

```
04-02 20:47:58.223: E/log-tag(699): before the first try
04-02 20:47:58.223: E/log-tag(699): after the httpclient
04-02 20:47:58.282: E/log-tag(699): after the httppostt
04-02 20:47:58.352: W/System.err(699): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.2 refused
04-02 20:47:58.362: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
04-02 20:47:58.362: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-02 20:47:58.362: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-02 20:47:58.362: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.getData(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:60)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at com.taseen.apps.TestExternalDatabaseActivity.onCreate(TestExternalDatabaseActivity.java:38)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-02 20:47:58.372: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 20:47:58.475: W/System.err(699):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 20:47:58.482: W/System.err(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-02 20:47:58.482: W/System.err(699):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-02 20:47:58.482: W/System.err(699):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 20:47:58.482: W/System.err(699): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.2:80 - Connection refused
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
04-02 20:47:58.493: W/System.err(699):  ... 21 more
04-02 20:47:58.493: E/log-tag(699): error in the get data function
```

## getAllCustomers.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("TestDatabase", $con) or die("can not connect to the database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}
  print(json_encode($output));

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Your erro are here "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.2 refused" the host are refusing a connection, try access it with a browser first.

Comment: A question: "HttpPost("127.0.0.2/getAllCustomers.php")" should not be "HttpPost("127.0.0.1/getAllCustomers.php")"?

Comment: this is the ip of the localhost how it can be that the system do not accept it ??

Comment: the localhost from the emulator of the android is 127.0.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i had a similiar problem.

I solved it as below

Access cmd in your computer and type ipconfig, get your Ip address and replace where is 127.0.0.2

something like that (in case of my computer):

```
HttpPost httppost = new  HttpPost("192.168.0.5/getAllCustomers.php");
```

I holpe it works

If don't works try turn off your antivirus, in my case avast is blocking my access.

Comment: it work  thank you for your help but i still get another error in the getData function